# Function apply with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm working on a promise-based project in Node.js using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/), and another in native promises by ES6. In both, I have a chain where I query a database in the following form:

```
some_function(/*...*/)

    .then(function () {
        return query("SELECT `whatever` FROM `wherever` ")
    })

    .then(/*...*/)
```

Note that `query` obviously returns a promise resolved to the query result.
This repeats in several chains, and I'm looking for a way to clean up the unused function wrapper.

I'd naturally use [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), but in this case, when I try:

```
.then(query.apply(this, ["SELECT * FROM ... "]))
.then(function(rows){ /*...*/ })
```

The next function in the chain gets `rows` as `undefined`.

Thanks from ahead. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) instead of apply: `.then(query.bind(query, "SELECT * FROM ... "))`.  You can use .bind() to create a new function based on `query` with your SQL string [partially applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: `apply` *calls* the method (it doesn't return a partially applied function), so you're not passing the query function to `then`, but the return value of it.

Comment: Wait, is that `return query.apply("SELECT …")` or `return query("SELECT …")`? In the first case, you have an `.apply` method that is *not* the `Function.prototype` one. Don't mix them up.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the correction. This error is not from the code, just the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a function reference to `.then()` so your choices are as follows:

1. Use an inline anonymous function as you are.
2. Create your own utility function that returns another function (see example below)
3. Use `.bind()` to create another function.

**The inline anonymous**

```
some_function(/*...*/).then(function () {
    return query.apply("SELECT `whatever` FROM `wherever` ")
}).then(/*...*/)
```

**Your own function wrapper**

```
function queryWrap(q) {
    return function() {
        return query.apply(q);
    }
}

some_function(/*...*/)
  .then(queryWrap("SELECT `whatever` FROM `wherever` "))
  .then(/*...*/)
```

This wrapper could be useful if you could use it in multiple places.  Probably not worth it for just one invocation.

**Use .bind()**

```
some_function(/*...*/)
  .then(query.apply.bind(query, "SELECT `whatever` FROM `wherever` "))
  .then(/*...*/)
```

Comment: In the last example with `bind()`, why did you use `query.apply.bind(/*...*/)`? Shouldn't it be `query.bind(/*...*/)`?
Thanks for the answer though. :)

Answer (score 4):

In es6, arrow functions solve this best:

```
.then(() => query.apply("SELECT `whatever` FROM `wherever` "))
.then(rows => { /*...*/ })
```

Comment: Hey, nice solution but solves only one of the cases mentioned.
Thanks!